# Find the least prime $p$, such that for some positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $(ab + a - b)(bc + b - c)(cd + c - d)(da + d - a) = 2023^2p.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

**Problem**

Find the least prime $p$, such that for some positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $(ab + a - b)(bc + b - c)(cd + c - d)(da + d - a) = 2023^2p.$

- This problem is from the algebra round of a high school math competition that has ended.

**My Work**

Odd primes work, because if $a=b=c=1$, we will be left with $2d-1 = 2023^2*p$.

To see if $p$ could be 2, we can plug it in!
We have: RHS = $2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 17^4$.
Therefore, we know that out of the four factors, three have to be odd and one is even.

$$\big((a-1)(b+1)+1\big)\big((b-1)(c+1)+1\big)\big((c-1)(d+1)+1\big)\big((d-1)(a+1)+1\big)= 2 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 17^4$$

Let us say that $((a-1)(b+1)+1)$ is even. $((a-1)(b+1)+1)$ will only be even if both $a$ and $b$ are even. The second term in the equation can not be equal to $1$, but if $c$ and $d$ are equal to $1$, the third and fourth term could be equal to $1$. We can create some cases, and if any case works, $p=2$ would work for the equation.

**Case 1**: $c=d=1$

In this case, the last two terms of the LHS are 1, which would not affect the product. The second term would simplify into $3b-2$. We can see that $b$ can not be even in this scenario, because then both the first and second term of the LHS would be even, which would not work.

We need two more cases on if $b$ is even or odd.

Is this the correct?

**I am having trouble finishing the problem.** Could I please receive some help? Thank you.

Comment: Your argument involving $a=b=2$ is incorrect. You need to deal with all pairs of even numbers such that precisely one of them is divisible by $4$.

Comment: @user1172706 You are right!!! I will go fix that later. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I have now completed all cases. I'll have a look to see if anything can be simplified but let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Why is it the case that precisely one of them is divisible by 4?

Comment: @Gary Liang Because if both or neither of them was divisible by four then one factor would be divisible by four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach, which
collects as many ideas as possible to sieve.
Some order is brought into the mess by using a tabular form,
when the information can be systematically presented.

It may be that somebody comes up with a really short solution by
exploiting the one or the other idea in a cleverer manner or
with a complementary new argument. The solution given
is the one that i may have written in an Olympiad contest till they would have forced me
to submit the many sheets of paper.
I am not quite happy with this solution, so i waited till the bounty is over.
Let's start.

---

---

Let us use the notations:
$$
X = 2\cdot 2023^2=2\cdot 7^2\cdot 17^4\ ,
\\
N(a,b)=ab+a-b=(a-1)(b+1)+1\ .
$$
As the OP also mentions, the case of $p=2$ is the only one of interest,
so it remains to show:

> The product of the four numbers $N(a,b)$, $N(b,c)$, $N(c,d)$, $N(d,a)$ is not $X$ for any choice of integers $a,b,c,d>0$.

*Proof:*

$\bbox[yellow]{(1)}$
We first observe that $N(a,b)\in\{1,2\}$, i.e. $(a-1)(b+1)\in \{0,1\}$, cannot be realized, since the factor $(b+1)$ is at least two. Same for the other numbers.

$\bbox[yellow]{(2)}$
A further observation concerns the numbers $a,b,c,d$ taken modulo four.
At one and exactly one of the four factors is $2$ modulo four.
After cyclic replacement, assume it is $N(a,b)=(a-1)(b+1)+1$. So $(a-1)(b+1)=1$ modulo four, so $(a-1)=(b+1)=\pm 1$ modulo four. So $(a,b)$ is either
$(0,2)$ or $(2,0)$. And the other two numbers, $c,d$ are not among $0,2$, else we have one more even factor.

So modulo four we have after using the cyclic symmetry one of the patterns
$(0,2,\pm1,\pm 1)$ or $(2,0,\pm1,\pm1)$.

$\bbox[yellow]{(3)}$ From
$$
%\prod_{\text{cyclic}} (a-1)(a+1)
%=
\prod_{\text{cyclic}} (a-1)(b+1)
<
%\prod_{\text{cyclic}} ((a-1)(b+1)+1)
%=
\underbrace{\prod_{\text{cyclic}} N(a,b)}_{=X=2\cdot 2023^2}
%=
%\prod_{\text{cyclic}} (ab+a-b)
<
\prod_{\text{cyclic}} a(b+1)
%=
%\prod_{\text{cyclic}} (a-1)(a+1)
$$
we obtain a useful double inequality:
$$
\prod_{\text{cyclic}} (a-1)(a+1)
<2\cdot 2023^2
<
\prod_{\text{cyclic}} a(a+1)\ .
$$
It is handy to use a notation for the product, and their pieces.
Let $K(a):=(a-1)(a+1)$, $L(a):=a(a+1)$. We set for pairs the $K$-value and the
$L$-value to be $K(a,b):=K(a)K(b)$,
$L(a,b):=L(a)L(b)$, and the same for triples, and for the quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$. So:
$$K(a,b,c,d)< 2\cdot 2023^2 < L(a,b,c,d)\ .$$

$\bbox[yellow]{(4)}$
The next observation concerns the small(er) factors.
At least one of the four factors is $\le X^{1/4}=(2\cdot 7^2)^{1/4}\cdot 17<625^{1/4}\cdot 17=5\cdot 17=85$. The divisors of $X$ in this range are $1,2,7,14,17,34,49$.
We may and do assume that $N(a,b)$ is this divisor.
For a special choice of $(a,b)$ we denote by $\Pi=\Pi(a,b)$ the value of
$N(b,c)\; N(c,d)\; N(d,a)=X/N(a,b)$.
Then at least one of these three factors is a divisor
$D\ne 1,2$ which is less or equal $\Pi^{1/3}$, and we list the possibilities.
Then we tabulate the cases:
$$
\scriptstyle
\begin{array}{|r|r|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
N(a,b) & (a-1)(b+1) &(a-1,b+1) & (a,b) & \Pi   & D\ :\ D^3\le \Pi
\\
\hline
1 & 0 & - & - & - & - \\\hline
%
2 & 1 & - & - & - & - \\\hline
%
7 & 6 & (3,2)\ (2,3)\ (1,6) & (4,1)\ (3,2)\ (2,5) & 2\cdot 7\cdot 17^4 & 
7,\ 14,\ 17,\ 34\\\hline
%
14 & 13 & (1,13) & (2,12) &  7\cdot 17^4 & 
7,\ 17\\\hline
%
17 & 16 & (8,2)\ (4,4)\ (2,8)\ (1,16) & (9,1)\ (5,3)\ (3,7)\ (2,15) &  2\cdot7^2\cdot 17^3 & 
7,\ 14,\ 17,\ 34,\ 49\\\hline
%
34 & 33 & (11,3)\ (3,11)\ (1,33) & (12,2)\ (4,10)\ (2,32) &  7^2\cdot 17^3 & 
7,\ 17,\ 49\\\hline
%
\color{magenta}{49} & 48 & (24,2)\ (16,3)\ (12,4)\ (8,6)\ (6,8) & 
\color{red}{(25,1)\ (17,2)\ (13,3)\ (9,5)\ (7,7)}
&  2\cdot 17^4 & 
17,\ 34\\
 &  & (4,12)\ (3,16)\ (2,24)\ (1, 48) &
\color{red}{(5,11)\ (4,15)\ (3,23)\ (2, 47)}
 &   & \\
\hline
%
\end{array}
$$
The column $(a,b)$ shows possible values for $(a,b)$,
realizing the few values for $N(a,b)$.
In the last column we have possible $D$-values, which are also in the table
in this first column.

$\bbox[yellow]{(5)}$ The case $N(a,b)=\color{magenta}{49}$ is annoying. Let us eliminate it.
Assume we can realize it. Let $D'$ be the even factor of $\Pi=X/49=2\cdot 17^4$ among $N(b,c)$, $N(c,d)$, $N(d,a)$.
The case $2\cdot 17^4$ is excluded, else the two remained factors are equal to one.
The case $2\cdot 17^3$ is excluded, else one of the two remained factors is   one.

So there remain only the cases $D'=2\cdot 17=34$,
which can be realized by the pairs
$\color{blue}{(12,2),\ (4,10),\ (2,32)}$,
and $D'=2\cdot 17^2=578=577+1$,
and since $577$ is prime we can realize this number only as $\color{blue}{(2,576)}$.

*Can $D'$ be $N(b,c)$ or $N(d,a)$, i.e. a factor appearing cyclically immediately before or after $N(a,b)$?*
We consider the cases:.

- For $(a,b)=(12,2)$. There is no $(d,a)=(?,12)$ in the red cell. But there is an $(a,b)=(2,47)$ in that red cell.
  We must examine the case $(d,a,b)=(12,2,47)$. Which leads to $(46c + 47)(13c - 12)=17^3$. The smaller factor $13c-12$ must be either $1$ or $17$. No solution.
- For $(4,10)$. There is no $(10,?)$ and no $(?,4)$ in the red cell.
- For $(2,32)$. There is no $(32,?)$ in the red cell. But there is a
  $(17,2)$ match. We must examine the case $(d,a,b)=(17,2,32)$. Which leads to $(31c + 32)(18c - 17)=17^3$. The smaller factor $18c-17$ must be either $1$ or $17$. No solution.
- For $(2,576)$. There is no $(576,?)$ in the red cell. But there is a
  $(17,2)$ match. We must examine the case $(d,a,b)=(17,2,576)$. Which leads to $(575c + 576)(18c - 17)=17^3$. The smaller factor $18c-17$ must be either $1$ or $17$. No solution.

So the red pair $(a,b)$ has no "collision" with the blue pair realizing $D'$, which means that we have all possible $a,b,c,d$ values, obtained by the cartesian product of the red set of all $(a,b)$ with the blue set
of all $(c,d)$. We first eliminate the case $(a,b)=\color{red}{(25,1)}$. In this case,
$a=25$ leads to the following possible values for $N(d,a)$:

$N(2,25)=1\cdot 16+1=27=3^3$, $N(10,25)=9\cdot 26+1=235=5(\dots)$,
$N(32,25)=31\cdot 26+1=807=3(\dots)$, $N(576,25)=575\cdot 26+1=14951$ which is a prime.

In the other cases, we will apply the $K$-test or the $L$-test from $(3)$.

The $K$-test eliminates $(2,576)$, since $K(2,576)=1\cdot 3\cdot575\cdot 577>2\cdot (2023/4)^2 $
So we must pair the blue $(c,d)=(2,576)$ with a red entry with $K$-value $K(a,b)$
smaller than $X/K(2,576)$ thus smaller than $\frac{2\cdot 2023^2}{2\cdot (2023/4)^2}=16$.
There is no such a small value, since $\max(a,b)\ge 7$, thus $K(a,b)\ge 5\cdot 7$.

The remained $K$-values and $L$-values are:

$K(12,2)=429$, $K(4,10)=1485$, $K(2,32)=3069$.

$L(12,2)=936$, $L(4,10)=2200$, $L(2,32)=6336$.

$K(17, 2) = 864$,
$K(13, 3) = 1344$,
$K(9, 5) = 1920$,
$K(7, 7) = 2304$,
$K(5, 11) = 2880$,
$K(4, 15) = 3360$,
$K(3, 23) = 4224$,
$K(2, 47) = 6624$.

$L(17, 2) = 1836$,
$L(13, 3) = 2184$,
$L(9, 5) = 2700$,
$L(7, 7) = 3136$,
$L(5, 11) = 3960$,
$L(4, 15) = 4800$,
$L(3, 23) = 6624$,
$L(2, 47) = 13536$.

We consider the blue values one by one.

- For $(12,2)$ we have a relatively "small" $L$-value, $L(12,2)=936<2023/2$, so it can be paired with a red $L$-value which must be bigger
  $4\cdot 2023$. Only $L(2, 47) = 13536$ is big enough. But then $(a,b,c,d)=(2,47,12,2)$ leads to a factor $N(d,a)=N(2,2)=1\cdot 3+1=4=2^2$. Failure.
- For $(2,32)$ we have a relatively "big" $K$-value, $K(2,32)=3069 > 2023\cdot \frac32$, so it can be paired with a red $K$-value which must be smaller
  $\frac 43\cdot 2023<\frac 43\cdot 2025=2700$. Only two red pairs do correspond, $(17,2)$ and $(13,3)$.
  But then $(a,b,c,d)$ is either $(17,2,2,32)$ or $(13,3,2, 32)$, so we have one factor $N(d,a)$ which is either $N(32,17)=559=13\cdot 43$,
  or $N(32,13)=435=5(\dots)$. Failure.
- For the remained blue pair, $(4,10)$, the $K$-value is moderate, $1485 >\frac 23\cdot 2023$.
  It rejects $(2,47)$ with $K$-value bigger $3\cdot 2023$.
  The $L$-value $L(4,10)=2200$ is also moderate, but better, it rejects red pairs with value smaller
  $2\cdot 2023^2/2200>2\cdot 2000^2/2500=3200$. So there remain the pairs
  $(5,11)$, $(4,15)$, $(3,23)$. We compute
  $N(10,5)=9\cdot 6+1=55=5\cdot 11$ and
  $N(10,4)=9\cdot 5+1=46=2\cdot 23$ and
  $N(10,3)=9\cdot 4+1=37$. In each case there is an alien prime involved.

$\bbox[yellow]{(6)}$
After excluding the $49$-case for one and/or any factor,
the table of possibilities can be actualized to:
$$
\scriptstyle
\begin{array}{|r|r|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
N(a,b) & (a-1)(b+1) &(a-1,b+1) & (a,b) & \Pi   & D\ :\ D^3\le \Pi
\\
\hline
7 & 6 & (3,2)\ (2,3)\ (1,6) & (4,1)\ (3,2)\ (2,5) & 2\cdot 7\cdot 17^4 & 
7,\ 14,\ 17,\ 34\\\hline
%
14 & 13 & (1,13) & (2,12) &  7\cdot 17^4 & 
7,\ 17\\\hline
%
17 & 16 & (8,2)\ (4,4)\ (2,8)\ (1,16) & (9,1)\ (5,3)\ (3,7)\ (2,15) &  2\cdot7^2\cdot 17^3 & 
7,\ 14,\ 17,\ 34\\\hline
%
34 & 33 & (11,3)\ (3,11)\ (1,33) & (12,2)\ (4,10)\ (2,32) &  7^2\cdot 17^3 & 
7,\ 17\\\hline
%
\end{array}
$$
Can this $D$ from the last column be realized by a factor cyclically "near" $N(a,b)$? In other words, can it be that this $D$ is on position $D=N(b,c)$, or on position $D=N(d,a)$?
Let us consider all these cases.
Such pairs realizing any value of $D$ from the last column are
already pairs from the column $(a,b)$ from the table.
Can we match two pairs from this column, so that one ends in the number
which is the start for the other pair?
Recall that matches must satisfy $(2)$.

- The case $(d,a)$ among $(4,1)$, $(9,1)$, $(3,7)$, $(2,15)$, $(4,10)$, $(2,32)$, there is no $(a,?)$ in the list.
- The case $(d,a)=(3,2)$ matches $(a,b)=(2,12)$ and $(a,b)=(2,32)$. (We ignore the match $(2,5)$ since after the $2$ there must be something equal to zero modulo four, condition $(2)$.) From $(d,a,b)=(3,2,12)$, resp. $(d,a,b)=(3,2,32)$ we obtain $(11c + 12)(4c - 3)=17^4$, resp. $(31c + 32)(4c - 3)=7\cdot 17^3$. The smaller factor $(4c-3)$ is one modulo four, must be one of the divisors $1$, $17$ in both cases, so $c=1$ or $c=5$, but then the other factor is too small. No solution.
- The case $(d,a)=(2,5)$ matches only $(a,b)=(5,3)$, and from $(d,a,b)=(2,5,3)$ we obtain $(3c - 2)(2c + 3)=2\cdot7\cdot 17^3$. The bigger factor $3c-2$ must be the even one, so it is at least $2\cdot 17^2$, but then the remained factor is too small to have a ratio of $\approx 3/2$ of the factors. (The ratio is at least two.)
- The case $(2,12)$ for $N(a,b)=14$ can be paired only with $(12,2)$ from the list. But this is excluded by $(2)$, or by the fact (same thing) that in the line $N(a,b)=14$ we allow only $D=7,17$.
- The case $(d,a)=(5,3)$ matches only $(a,b)=(3,2)$, (since $(3,23)$ contradicts $(2)$,) and from $(d,a,b)=(5,3,2)$ we obtain $(6c - 5)(c + 2)=2\cdot7\cdot 17^3$. The smaller factor $c+2$ must be the even one, so it is in the list $14, 34$, but then the remained factor is too small to have a ratio of $\approx 3/2$ of the factors. (The ratio is at least two.)
- The case $(d,a)=(12,2)$ matches only $(a,b)$ equal to $(2,5)$.
  For $(d,a,b)=(12,2,5)$ we obtain the equation
  $(13c - 12)(4c + 5)=7\cdot 17^3$. The smaller factor $4c+5$ must be in $(5, 17^2)$, cannot have the factor $7$ by test modulo four, so it is $17$. This gives $c=3$, but then $13c-12=27=3^3$ has alien factors.
  (Note: There is no match $(2,32)$ since for $N(d,a)=N(12,2)=34$ we are interested in a $D$ among $7, 17$, but $(2,32)$ occurs for $N(2,32)=34$.)

We conclude that $(a,b)$ is one of the pairs in the same name column from the table, and the factor $D$ comes as $N(c,d)$, where $(c,d)$ is also a pair from the same column, since it corresponds to a value $D$ among $7,14,17,34$, and the table covers the possibilities for other names of the variables.

$\bbox[yellow]{(7)}$ Let us arrange now the pairs in columns, by taking the values modulo four:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c||c|c|}
\hline
0\text{ and }2 &\pm 1\text{ and }\pm 1 &&
0\text{ and }\pm 1 &2\text{ and }\pm 1 &
\\\hline
(2,12) & (9,1) && (4,1) & (3,2)\\
(12,2) & (5,3) &&       & (2,5)\\
(4,10) & (3,7) &&       & (2,15)\\
(2,32) &       &&       &\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
By $(6)$ $(a,b)$ is one pair in the table, and the $(c,d)$ realizing the $D$ from $(6)$ is an other one. So we have all the possibilities for $(a,b,c,d)$, which is cyclically the same as $(c,d,a,b)$. Moreover, by $(2)$, the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are taken either from the first two columns, or from the last two columns. And the two pairs come from different  columns.

- We exclude that $(a,b)=(4,1)$ and $(c,d)$ are taken from the last two columns, seeing that $(c,d)=(2,?)$ is not an option, because in $(4,1,2,?)$ the  even values are not consecutive, contradicting $(2)$, and in the remained case $(a,b,c,d)=(4,1,3,2)$ the $L$-value is too small. Or by looking at $N(d,a)=N(2,4)=1\cdot 5+1=6=2\cdot 3$ with an alien factor.
- It remains the case when $(a,b)$ comes from the first column, and $(c,d)$ from the second one. I found it easy to check the $L$-values. In the first column the $L$-values are $L(2,12)=L(12,2)=2\cdot 3\cdot 12\cdot 13=936$,
  $L(4,10)=4\cdot 5\cdot 10\cdot 11=2200$, $L(2,32)=2\cdot 3\cdot 32\cdot 33=6336$. In the second column $L(9,1)=180$, $L(5,3)=360$, $L(3,7)=672$.
  So the product is
  $$L(a,b,c,d)=L(a,b)L(c,d)\le L(2,32)L(3,7)<7000\cdot 700=4900000
  <2\cdot 2000^2<X\ .
  $$
  This contradicts $(3)$.

This concludes the solution.

$\square$

Comment: At the very start you claim that $N(a,b)=1$ cannot be realized, but $N(1,b)=1$ for any choice of $b$. Later at point $(5)$ you exclude two cases because otherwise $N(x,y)=1$ for some $x$, $y$, but this is not impossible as far as I can tell. Could you clarify this please?

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for pointing it out, i have to reread, get again inside the matter and rethink, it is a long time since things were written. I remember only that the table in (5) was done for the case $N(1,b)=1$, too, but i had some reasons to avoid going into it in detail. The text was strongly rearranged short before putting all the arguments together, so a miss is good possible. I will fill in the gap as soon as i can.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I understand it's quite the effort to pick these ideas back up again. For some reason this question got bumped back to me, and that prompted me to look for the cleanest and quickest way to solve this; my own half-answer is not satisfying. You have some good ideas here, but also not the whole picture yet it seems. I look forward to your update.

Answer (score 1):

(Hm, this doesnt' work out as easily as I thought it would, so ignore for now.)

$ab+a-b) = (a-1)(b+1) + 1$.
So if $ab+a-b = 1$, this just requires $a = 1$ (with no restrictions on $b$).
Show that $p$ odd can be achieved.
So it just remains to consider if $p = 2$ can be achieved.
I'm guessing that it can't be, but don't know why not.

---

Random musings

- The RHS has 7 prime factors.

  - This means that one of the terms on the LHS is either 1 or prime (they can't all be composite).
- We can simplify the expression if one of the terms is 1.
- If $ab+a - b = p$, then $(a-1)(b+1) = ab+a -b - 1 = p-1$
- Can $p = 2$?

  - $ab+a-b = 2 $ has no positive integer solutions (Only solutions are $(0, -2), (2, 0)$).
    So $ab+a - b = 2n$, where $ n \mid 2023^2$
  - $(a-1)(b+1) = 2n-1$. We could have $ a  = 2, b = 2n-2$.
  - $a = 1, b = 1$ gives $(cd+c-d)(2d-1) = 2023^2 \times 2$. The only integer solution is $(-8185058, 0)$.
  - $ a = 1, c = 1$ gives $(2b-1)(2d-1) = 2023^2 \times 2$ which has no solutions.
  - $ a = 1$, Wolfram claims that there are no positive integers solutions.
  - $ a = 2, 3$, Wolfram ran out of standard computation time.

Comment: In the $a\ne1$ case one can proceed as given in my "answer" but it looks as if the organisers had spotted something else about the algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=b=c=1$ then the equation reduces to $2d-1=2023^2p$ and there are solutions for all odd $p$.  So we can concentrate on $p=2$.
$$(ab+a-b)(bc+b-c)(cd+c-d)(da+d-a)=2.7^2.17^4$$
For the LHS to be singly even we can suppose, w.l.g., that $a$ and $d$ are odd and that $b$ and $c$ are even, with precisely one divisible by $4$.

It will be convenient to dispose of a few cases before starting the main proof.

IF $d=15$.

Then one factor is $14a+15\equiv 1$ (mod $14$). The only such factor of the RHS is $1$, a contradiction.

IF $d=9$.

Then one factor is $10c-9\equiv 3$ (mod $4$). Therefore $10c-9=7.17^i$. The only possibility modulo $10$ is when $i=3$ and then $c=3440$.

Then $c<bc+b-c\le 2.7.17$, a contradiction.

IF $d=3$.

Then one factor is $4c-3\equiv 5$ (mod $8$). But all odd factors of the RHS are $ \equiv \pm 1$ (mod $8$).

IF $d=1$.

$$(ab+a-b)(bc+b-c)(2c-1)=2.7^2.17^4$$
Then $2c-1\equiv 3$ (mod $4$) and therefore $2c-1=7.17^k\equiv 7$ (mod $16$) i.e. $c \equiv 4$ (mod $8$).

$$ab+a-b=7^q.17^i,bc+b-c=2.7^r.17^j,2c-1=7.17^k$$

If $k\ge 2$ then $bc+b-c\ge c+2$ is a factor of $4c-2$, the quotient being $2^{1-r}.17^{k-j}$. This is clearly impossible.

If $k=1$ then $2c-1=7.17$ and $c=60$. Then $61b-60$ is an even factor of $2.7.17^3$ but no such factor is $1$ (mod $61$).

Finally, if $k=0$ then $c=4$ and $(ab+a-b)(5b-4)=2.7.17^4$. Now $5b-4\equiv  6$ (mod $10$) and is therefore $2.7.17^2$ or $2.17^3$. Then $ab+a-b=17^2$ or $7.17$ and $a\ne 1$. Then we obtain the contradiction

$$5b>5b-4\ge 14(ab+a-b)>14(a-1)b$$

A PROOF THAT NO FACTOR OF THE LHS IS PRIME

By writing $uv+u-v=(u-1)(v+1)+1$ we see that the cases to be considered for $(u,v)$ to be $2,7$ or $17$ are $(2,5),(3,2),(4,1),(2,15),(3,7),(5,3),(9,1).$

The cases for $d$ that we have already dealt with mean that we just have the following further cases to consider.

**The case $a,b,2,5$**
$$(ab+a-b)(3b-2)(4a+5)=2.7.17^4$$
$4a+5=1$ or $7$ (mod $16$) and therefore $a\equiv 3$ (mod $4$). Then
$$4a+5=17^i,ab+a-b=7.17^j,3b-2=2.17^k$$
Since $a\ge 3$ and $b\ge 12$, $ab+a-b$ is the largest of the three factors and therefore $i=k=1,j=2$.

Then $a=3,b=12$ and $ab+a-b=27$, a contradiction.

**The case $3,2,c,d$**
$$(c+2)(cd+c-d)(4d-3)=2.7.17^4$$
Modulo $16$ the three factors are $1,1,7$ in some order. For the factor $4d-3$ we must have $d\equiv 1$ (mod $4$) and then
$$c+2=2.17^i,cd+c-d=7.17^j,4d-3=17^k$$
with $c\equiv 0$ (mod $32$) and $d\equiv 9$ (mod $16$).

Then $cd+c-d>31d>4d-3\ge 17^2$ and therefore $j\ge 2$. This gives the contradiction $i+j+k\ge 1+2+2=5$.

**The case $3,b,c,5$**
$$(2b+3)(bc+b-c)(6c-5)=2.7^2.17^3$$
$2b+3$ and $6c-5$ are both $3$ (mod $4$) and so we have
$$2b+3=7.17^i,bc+b-c=2.17^j,6c-5=7.17^k$$
Because of the cases already dealt with we know that no factor can be a single prime other than $17$ and so $i,j,k$ are all non-zero. Then,
considering the third factor mod $6$ gives $k=2$ and hence $i=j=1$.The factor $bc+b-c$ is then far too small compared to the other factors.

THERE ARE NO SOLUTIONS FOR $p=2$

The RHS is product of $7$ primes and therefore one factor of the LHS has fewer than $2$ primes. The only possibility is if $a=1$. Then
$$(bc+b-c)(cd+c-d)(2d-1)=2.7^2.17^4$$
$2d-1\equiv 1$(mod $16$) and therefore $d\equiv 1$(mod $8$). Then $cd+c-d\equiv 3$(mod $4$) and therefore $cd+c-d\equiv 7$(mod $16$). Since no factor is a prime, we have non-negative integers $i,j,k$ such that
$$bc+b-c=2.7.17^i,cd+c-d=7.17^{1+j},2d-1=17^{2+k}$$
$2(cd+c-d)>2d-1$ and so $j=1, i=k=0$. Then $bc+b-c=14$ and so $b=2,c=12$. Then $11d+12=7(2d-1)$ and $d=\frac {19}{3}$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a work in progress. It shows that, without loss of generality, any integral solution must have $c$ and $d$ even and $a$ and $b$ odd, and either $a=1$ or $b=1$ or both. It is quite a lot of casework, and some familiarity with modular arithmetic is assumed. I cannot imagine that this is the intended way to tackle this problem.

---

A bit of algebra shows that the given equation is equivalent to
$$\big((a-1)(b+1)+1\big)\big((b-1)(c+1)+1\big)\big((c-1)(d+1)+1\big)\big((d-1)(a+1)+1\big)=2023^2p.\tag{1}$$
Plugging in $a=b=c=1$ yields
$$2d-1=2023^2p,$$
which shows that we can get any odd prime, and in particular $p=3$.

For $p=2$ the right hand side of $(1)$ is congruent to $2$ mod $4$, and so precisely one of the four factors on the left hand side is even and congruent to $2$ mod $4$. Without loss of generality this means $a$ and $b$ are odd, and $c$ and $d$ are even.

If $a,b>1$ then each of the $4$ factors on the left hand side of $(1)$ is greater than $3$. The right hand side equals $2\times7^2\times17^4$, which has precisely $7$ prime factors counted with multiplicity. It follows that one of the factors on the left hand side must be a prime greater than $2$. Solving
$$(x-1)(y+1)+1=7\qquad\text{ or }\qquad (x-1)(y+1)+1=17,$$
yields $(x,y)\in\{(2,5),(3,2)\}$ in the former case, and in the latter case $(x,y)\in\{(2,15),(3,7),(5,3)\}$. As $a$ and $b$ are odd, and $c$ and $d$ are even, we find that $(a,b,c,d)=(2A-1,2B-1,2C,2D)$ must be one of
\begin{eqnarray}
&&(5,2B-1,2C,2),\\
&&(2A-1,3,2,2D),\\
&&(15,2B-1,2C,2),\\
&&(3,7,2C,2D),\\
&&(5,3,2C,2D).
\end{eqnarray}
We exclude each case separately:

1. If $(a,b,c,d)=(5,2B-1,2C,2)$, plugging the values into $(1)$ we find     that
   $$7(8B+1)(6C-2)\big(2(B-1)(2C+1)+1\big)=2\times7^2\times17^4.$$
   In particular the factor $(3C-1)$ is congruent to $2$ mod $3$ and so it is divisible by $17$, and $(8B+1)$ is congruent to $1$ mod $8$ and so it is a power of $17$. Then $B\in\{2,36,614\}$, and so the last factor is congruent to $3$ mod $4$ and hence a multiple of $7$. Then either $3C-1=17$ or $3C-1=17^3$, and so $C\in\{6,1638\}$. None of the four possible combinations of $B$ and $C$ satisfy the equation above.
2. If $(a,b,c,d)=(2A-1,3,2,2D)$, plugging the values into $(1)$ we find     that
   $$7(8A-7)(2D+2)\big(2A(2D-1)+1\big)=2\times7^2\times17^4.$$
   In particular the factor $(8A-7)$ is congruent to $1$ mod $8$, so it is a power of $17$. Then $A$ is odd and so the last factor is congruent to $3$ mod $4$, and hence a multiple of $7$. Then the factor $(D+1)$ is also a power of $17$ and so $D$ is a multiple of $16$. It follows that the last factor is the largest of the four. But then $8A-7=17$ and $D+1=17$, as both factors are greater than $1$, and so $A=3$ and $D=16$ leading to
   $$2A(2D-1)+1=187=17\times11,$$
   a contradiction.
3. If $(a,b,c,d)=(15,2B-1,2C,2)$, plugging the values into $(1)$ we find     that
   $$17(28B+1)(6C-2)\big(2(B-1)(2C+1)+1\big)+1)=2\times7^2\times17^4.$$
   In particular the factor $(28B+1)$ is odd and congruent to $1$ mod $7$, but this is impossible.
4. If $(a,b,c,d)=(3,7,2C,2D)$, plugging the values into $(1)$ we find that
   $$17(12C+7)(8D-3)\big((2C-1)(2D+1)+1\big)=2\times7^2\times17^4.$$
   In particular the factor $(8D-3)$ is congruent to $5$ mod $8$, but all odd factors of $2\times7^2\times17^4$ are congruent to $1$ or $3$ mod $8$, a contradiction.
5. If $(a,b,c,d)=(5,3,2C,2D)$, plugging the values into $(1)$ we find that
   $$17(4C+3)(12D-5)\big((2C-1)(2D+1)+1\big)=2\times7^2\times17^4.$$
   Note that the factors $(4C+3)$ and $(12D-5)$ are both congruent to
   $3$ mod $4$, so both are multiples of $7$. This means $C\equiv
   D\equiv1\pmod{7}$ and so the latter factor is congruent to $4$ mod
   $7$. It also means that the latter factor is twice a power of $17$,
   and so it must be $2\times17^2$. Then
   $$(2C-1)(2D+1)=2\times17^2-1=577,$$ implies that $C=1$ and $D=288$
   because $577$ is prime, but then $12D-5=7\times17\times29$, a
   contradiction.

This shows that there are no solutions with $a,b>1$.